# What is the differences between mysql-client and mysql-client-core?

Tags: mysql

I wonder what is the differences between mysql-client and mysql-client-core?
Also there are mysql-server and mysql-server-core.

Answer (score 11):

**mysql-client-core** - containts core client binaries for mysql database support while
**mysql-client** - depends on **mysql-client-core** and contains other extended features and utilities (for ex perl support)

Answer (score 7):

Now I'm using mysql-client-5.5 and mysql-client-core-5.5 on Ubuntu12.04 LTS.

I entered following commands, and retrieved the results.

```
dupingping@dupingping:~$ dpkg -L mysql-client-core-5.5
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1/mysqlcheck.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mysql.1.gz
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/mysql-client-core-5.5
/usr/share/doc/mysql-client-core-5.5/copyright
/usr/share/doc/mysql-client-core-5.5/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/mysqlcheck
/usr/bin/mysql

dupingping@dupingping:~$ dpkg -L mysql-client-5.5

/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1/mysql_plugin.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mysql_tableinfo.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mysqlslap.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mysqldumpslow.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mysqlimport.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mysqlman.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/innotop.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mysqlreport.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mysqlaccess.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mysqladmin.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mysql_find_rows.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mysqlshow.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mysql_client_test.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mysqlbug.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mysqldump.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mysql_waitpid.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/myisam_ftdump.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mysql_fix_extensions.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mysql_client_test_embedded.1.gz
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/mysql-client-5.5
/usr/share/doc/mysql-client-5.5/README
/usr/share/doc/mysql-client-5.5/README.Debian
/usr/share/doc/mysql-client-5.5/copyright
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/mysql_waitpid
/usr/bin/mysqladmin
/usr/bin/mysql_plugin
/usr/bin/mysqlshow
/usr/bin/mysqldump
/usr/bin/myisam_ftdump
/usr/bin/mysql_find_rows
/usr/bin/mysqlimport
/usr/bin/mysqlslap
/usr/bin/mysqlbug
/usr/bin/innochecksum
/usr/bin/mysqlaccess
/usr/bin/mysql_client_test
/usr/bin/mysqldumpslow
/usr/bin/innotop
/usr/bin/mysql_fix_extensions
/usr/bin/mysqlreport
/usr/share/man/man1/mysqloptimize.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mysqlrepair.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mysqlanalyze.1.gz
/usr/share/doc/mysql-client-5.5/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/bin/mysqloptimize
/usr/bin/mysqlanalyze
/usr/bin/mysqlrepair
```

As you can see it, mysql-client package includes the client binaries and the additional tools innotop and mysqlreport, but mysql-client-core only includes the core client files as `/usr/bin/mysql`, `/usr/bin/mysqlcheck`.

And about mysql-server.

> This is an empty package that depends on the current "best" version of 
>   mysql-server (currently mysql-server-5.5), as determined by the MySQL 
>   maintainers.(**mysql-server**)
>
> This package includes the server binaries but doesn't contain all the 
>   infrastructure needed to setup system databases.(**mysql-server-core**)